# change layers on the button click

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am new to `angularjs` and `web development`. Here, I am trying to implement the layer thing.

So, I have a button on that I want user to remain on the same page but the text data should be changed .See, I have  `text-angualr` which I user for showing some data to user. 
Now,

```
  <div text-angular id="htmlEditorId" ng-class="(totalOrphans == 0 ? 'add-heightTo-textEditor' : 'html-editor-container') + ' ' + ((documentType === 'jobDescription') ? 'add_jd_height' : 'html-editor-container')" class="textcontent-modal"
                    spellcheck="false" ng-model="data.htmlDocument" ta-disabled="isEditingDisabled" ng-mouseup="doSomethingWithSelectedText($event)"
                    ng-mouseover="show_Tool_Tip_OnHover($event)" ng-onkeyup="doSomethingWithSelectedText($event)" name="editor1"
                    title="{{show_tool_tip ? annotation_name : ''}}">
                </div>
```

Now, In this I show user whole data and also highlight some part of that data depends on some conditions , This is working fine for me. But Now I want change this thing. So, It should be like first It will show the text without highlighting and then when user clicks on some button then there itself that will come in highlighted text. So, That is kind of layer thing .

So, for that i have added one more div which is the same text-angular

```
<div text-angular id="originalId" ng-class="(totalOrphans == 0 ? 'add-heightTo-textEditor' : 'html-editor-container') + ' ' + ((documentType === 'jobDescription') ? 'add_jd_height' : 'html-editor-container')" class="textcontent-modal"
                    spellcheck="false" ng-model="data.originalDocument" ta-disabled="isEditingDisabled" ng-mouseup="doSomethingWithSelectedText($event)">
                </div>
```

but ng-model will be different.

Now,

```
<button class="col-xs-3 btn btn-default" ng-click="changeTab()">NextTab </button>
```

I have this button on which It should change that ,

I actually looked `z-index` is one thing that we can do  , But I am new to this so, any hint or help will be great for me to start . Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question.

Comment: I mean On click of the button a div should change its content.